# Create chat group in SignalR

Tags: signalr

How can I create a chat group in SignalR?  I tried to find some examples and they weren't helpful.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
public void CreateGroup(string currentUserId, string toConnectTo)
{
    string strGroupName = GetUniqueGroupName(currentUserId, toConnectTo);
    string connectionId_To = OnlineUser.userObj.Where(item => item.userId == toConnectTo).Select(item => item.connectionId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionId_To))
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, strGroupName);
        Groups.Add(connectionId_To, strGroupName);
        Clients.Caller.setChatWindow(strGroupName, toConnectTo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not such easy to create a user friendly chat group that I'm currently working on.

I use sql database, user can register, login, logout, close browser or phone app without logout.

user can create own group, add members to group, delete member from group.

when user send message, call signalr Server method and store message in sql, then Server send message to all users in the same group.  if some users are offline, they read message from sql when online again.

the input for the message can be a 'contenteditable div' so that user can add images and formatted text to the message.

something like that!